# Heroku push rejected (Django app)

Tags: django, heroku, github

I'm deploying a Django app to GitHub and Heroku.
I have deployed it first to GitHub, removing (putting it in the .gitignore file) "settings.py", and now that I'm trying to push it to Heroku, I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named settings
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

How can I avoid to push some file to GitHub, but at the same having the possibility to pushing it to Heroku?

UPDATE:

I've tried to keep settings.py and temp_settings.py separate, but now the app doesn't work anymore. That's the traceback when I try to run the local server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/stefano/projects/blog-project/blogproject/settings.py", line 104, in <module>
    DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
NameError: name 'DATABASES' is not defined
```

It seems settings.py can't "reach" temp_settings.py, as I've cut-paste all of the database settings in temp_settings. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is not to ignore settings.py file from your code base. Instead, do something like:

```
try:
    from temp_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

at the end of settings.py file and add temp_settings.py to .gitignore

For the credentials that you need to keep private, use temp_settings.

Comment: I've tried and, when pushed to GitHub, _private_ credentials on "settings.py" are between sort of a tag, like this: "<<<<<<< HEAD
=======", but they are there, I mean: they aren't hidden

Comment: That is nothing to do with private credentials; it is the result of a bad merge in git. You need to fix it.

Comment: Now it's ok, but the app doesn't work anymore, as it can't "reach" the data of the "temp_settings.py" file. I'm updating the question.

Comment: In order to reach the "temp_settings.py" file, it should be in the same directory as your settings.py file.

Could you please share your directory structure if you can?